# Is Vyāsa being the compiler/divider/arranger of Vedas recorded anywhere in the Vedas themselves?

Tags: vedas, history, vyasa

There are several Purāṇic references, e.g., [SB 12.6.50](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish#page/n2185/mode/2up) that say Vyāsa (Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana) arranged the disorganized Vedic mantras into four parts:

> 50. Just as (out of a heap of mixed up) 
>   precious stones of the same kind are assorted and kept in 
>   separate heaps, he (Vyāsa) selected and classified the Vedic 
>   Mantras as belonging to the category of the Ṛg, Atharvan, 
>   Yajus, and Sāman and thus compiled four *Saṃhitās* or collections out of those (formerly mixed up) *Mantras*.

However, do any of the Vedas themselves say this?

Comment: Like Sutras don't mention their commentators, Vedas don't mention their compiler.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Vedas have supplements called [Pariśiṣṭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pariśiṣṭa) so that is where one could look to answer this.

Comment: @sv. u can change title to Pariśiṣṭa then...

Answer (score -2):

Consider the following mantra from Purusha Sukta [10.90.9](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10090.htm)

> From that great general sacrifice Ṛcas and Sāma-hymns were born:
>   Therefrom were spells and charms produced; the Yajus had its birth
>   from it.

[Atharava Veda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36039/3869) as a veda is made up of Ricks mantras only.

According to Rig Veda [Anukramanika](http://voiceofdharma.org/books/rig/ch1.htm), the composer of this hymn is nArAyana, but not Vyasa.

[Tenth Mandala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda#Mandalas) is supposed to be latest one.  However, even this hymn did not mention Vyasa to be compiler of Vedas.

---

Hence, division of Veda by the Sage Vyasa must be an interpolated story.

Comment: This answer is full of fallacies. The Anukramani tells who revealed the mantras, not who divided the Vedas. The mention of Rik, Sama, Yajur is reference to mantra types, not division of Vedas.

Comment: 1. The question is about mention of the Sage Vyasa, who was attributed for dividing vedas, in veda. So answer followed it.  2) "full of fallacies!". Please list out those fallacies. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Whoever down voted my answer should be courageous enough to state the reasons.   Otherwise it tells upon their cowardice only.

Comment: This is not for the first time that I am in receipt of down voting.  In spite complaining the moderators remained silent.  Silence on the part of moderators can be inferred that they are encouraging such acts of down voting without mentioning the reason.

Comment: Downvoting has nothing to do with person's courage or cowardice. Something which says -1 I downvoted for so and so is what you should look for. This answer contains a comment from Ikshvaku why this answer is wrong. Sometimes is quite clear why an answer is downvoted. Sometimes you should understand based on the feedback . It depends on the answer. Moderators do not have any rule in encouraging downvoting or to be clear, stopping downvoting or upvoting. If you are  It's better to focus on content rather than blaming the moderators.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Your answer got downvoted because it's full of fallacies. For one, just because the Vedas do not mention something, doesn't mean it's an interpolation. And secondly, the reference to rik, saman, and yajus are mantra types, not separate Vedas.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but the references to Ramayana are probably unnecessary. Vedas have supplements called [Pariśiṣṭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pariśiṣṭa) so that is where you could look. Re: downvotes, when you ask/answer something that goes against tradition/general beliefs you should expect a certain # of downvotes just because of that reason.